# Doing a POST request to a server and getting a specific cookie from the response

Tags: java, android, vb.net

I'm trying to port an old VB.NET application to an Android application, but due to my lack of Java experience I am unable to find this one out. I have tried multiple solutions but to no avail.

The idea is basically to do a POST request to 'http://login.vk.com/' and getting the response cookies.
If anyone could give me a hint on how to work with cookies on Android I'd appreciate it very much.

Original Code

```
    Public Sub Login(ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String)
    Try

        ' Make request
        Dim cont As New CookieContainer
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest
        request = WebRequest.Create("http://login.vk.com/")
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.CookieContainer = cont

        ' Create POST content and send
        Dim postdata As String = "act=login&success_url=&fail_url=&try_to_login=1&to=&vk=&al_test=3&email=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Username) & "&pass=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Password) & "&expire="
        Dim postbytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata)
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        request.ContentLength = postbytes.Length
        Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream
        requestStream.Write(postbytes, 0, postbytes.Length)
        requestStream.Close()

        ' Get response and login cookie
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse
        Dim cookies As CookieCollection = request.CookieContainer.GetCookies(New Uri("http://pirate.vk.com"))
        For Each myCookie As Cookie In cookies
            If myCookie.Name = "remixsid" Then
                Me.Guid = myCookie.Value
            End If
        Next
        response.Close()

        ' Throw error if cookie not found
        If Not IsLoggedIn Then Throw New Exception("Invalid login guid")

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Error at custom login", ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The code written so far:

```
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://login.vk.com/");

            try {
                List<NameValuePair> postData = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("act", "login"));
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("success_url", ""));
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fail_url", ""));
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("try_to_login", "1"));
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("to", ""));
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vk", ""));
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("al_test", ""));
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8")));
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8")));
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("expire", ""));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postData));

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch(Exception e) {

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way to get cookies in response:

```
private static HttpParams params;
params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);
HttpClientParams.setCookiePolicy(params, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://login.vk.com/");

            try {
                List<NameValuePair> postData = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("act", "login"));
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("success_url", ""));
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fail_url", ""));
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("try_to_login", "1"));
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("to", ""));
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vk", ""));
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("al_test", ""));
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8")));
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8")));
                postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("expire", ""));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postData));

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                List<Cookie> cookies = ((DefaultHttpClient)httpclient).getCookieStore().getCookies();
                for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
                Log.i("Cookie", cookie.toString());
             }

            } catch(Exception e) {

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you:

```
    HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;
//edit String data as what you want
    String data = "act=login&success_url=&fail_url=&try_to_login=1&to=&vk=&al_test=3&email=" & URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8")) & "&pass=" & URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8")) & "&expire="
        URL mUrl;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
        try {               
            mUrl = new URL("http://login.vk.com/");
            urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
            urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            //query is your body
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");            
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(data.length()));
            urlConn.setUseCaches (false);
            urlConn.setDoInput(true);
            urlConn.setDoOutput(true);

            //send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                    urlConn.getOutputStream ());
            wr.write(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
            wr.flush ();
            wr.close ();

            //Get Response  
            InputStream is = urlConn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;            
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
              response.append(line);
              response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            String result = response.toString();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {

              if(urlConn != null) {
                  urlConn.disconnect(); 
              }
        }
```